# siunitx: "inter-unit-product" doesn't work as expected

Tags: siunitx

I have an up-to-date MiKTeX 2.9 installation on Windows 10, and recently I came across a weird behavior of `siunitx` where `inter-unit-product` doesn't affect the output as shown below.

A couple of days ago, it was working but now it doesn't.
So, what might be the reason?

P.S. The log file can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/DMDL3vpP).

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
    per-mode=symbol,
    per-mode=repeated-symbol,
    inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}
}

\begin{document}
    \SI{4}{\left[\newton\m\s\per\radian\right]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You've stuck random stuff inside the unit: it will force literal mode ...

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you surround `\newton\m\s\per\radian` with `\left[` and `\right]`? Without those fences, the output of `\SI` is just fine.

Comment: Side comment: The unit should never be put in square brackets.

Comment: @JosephWright is there a warning about such behavior in the manual or the log file?

Comment: @Mico I am experimenting, and seemingly I messed it up.

Comment: @Diaa No, because some people prefer not to use the unit macro.s You can `forbid-literal-units` if you wish

Comment: @JosephWright If you don't mind, would you please tell me what option is responsible for printing `0.1234` as `0.123`, while `0.12` should be printed as it is without adding additional zero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If, for some unfathomable reason, you simply *must* encase scientific units in square brackets, you shouldn't do it as

```
\SI{4}{\left[\newton\m\s\per\radian\right]}
```

Instead, do it as follows (in math mode, naturally):

```
$4\left[\si{\newton\m\s\per\radian}\right]$
```

[image]

```
%%% to be compiled with either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{mathtools,unicode-math}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol,
         inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}} }
\begin{document}
    $4\left[\unit{\newton\m\s\per\radian}\right]$
\end{document}
```

That said, I would strongly recommend *against* encasing scientific units in square brackets.

Comment: Not only you, but rather the BIPM. `;-)`

Comment: May I know how to have control over the space surrounding the inter-product dot?

Comment: @Diaa - "Control over the space" is a rather broad objective. The option `inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}` makes LaTeX  insert a thinspace on either side of of `\cdot`, while `inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{\cdot}}` instructs LaTeX to insert no whitespace at all.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I rather found the space quite wide, which made me want to reduce it a bit without removing it at all.

Comment: @dias - My mind-reading skills are, sadly, rubbish. As a result, if a person asks me something but isn't clear about the objective, chances are nil that I will  guess that objective correctly.  :-( To get LaTeX to insert *half* a thinspace around `\cdot`, give `inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{\mkern1.5mu\cdot\mkern1.5mu}` a try. (Can you guess that 1thinspace=3mu?)

Comment: I just noticed you edited your comment after I last visited my question. For your last suggestion, it throws an error `Package siunitx Error: Unknown option '\ensuremath {\mkern 1.5mu\cdot \mkern(siunitx) 1.5mu}'. ...{\mkern1.5mu\cdot\mkern1.5mu}]{4}{\newton\m}`. However, I found that it can be simply done by introducing `\hspace` before/after `\cdot`. Furthermore, for my eyesight sharpness, `{}\cdot{}` gives the same spacing of `\cdot`.

Comment: @Diaa - options for siunitx commands must be surrounded by square brackets.